# How to save image in 4096 resolution into device gallery in android?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I want to save the `layout` as an `image` in `4096X4096` or `2048X2048` resolution into the device gallery without losing it's aspect ratio or the quality.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

```
private void getBitmap(View view) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    view.buildDrawingCache();

    Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
}
```

I'm getting the bitmap of a view from the above code. So how can i save it in the device with high resolution.

[Orignal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Gvo.jpg)
[Image after saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm2Re.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor.git) is a good image Conversion library. [**Resizer**](https://github.com/hkk595/Resizer.git) is inspired by the Compressor, it has better compression with high quality.

**Resize image**

```
    Bitmap resizedImage = new Resizer(this)
            .setTargetLength(2048)
            .setQuality(100)
            .setSourceImage(originalImage)
            .getResizedBitmap();
```

**Save image**

```
imageHolder.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = imageHolder.getDrawingCache();
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "filename", "description");
Toast.makeText(context, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

***Note:*** Use ImageView to set the image in your Activity. Give ID of ImageView as imageHolder. Give `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Permission in `AndroidManifest`

## ***Edit:***

**Convert layout to Bitmap**

```
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_view);
private File getBitmapFromView(layout){
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: How do i save this resized bitmap into the device? And how to convert constraint layout to bitmap?

Comment: @prakharshrivastava go through the above-edited answer, create an onClickListener to save the image and the snippet of saving the resized image.

Comment: What should i pass instead of originalImage?

Comment: You have to set the resized image to a ImageView and give id to it as imageHolder or what ever name you like and create a onclicklistener with the above snippet to save the image present in the imageview

Comment: I cannot be able to resize the bitmap because setSourceImage needs the type file and i have the bitmap.

Comment: Can you show me the code by editing the question. Since you asked what is right procedure I have given u the links

Comment: I have a layout which i want to save as an image in the device. But the lib Resizer doesn't resize the layout it only resize the image file. I've also edited the answer

Comment: I have edited the answer for your request plz go though it. If the answer is justified to your question please drop a tick mark below the voting pole it really helps. Thank you

Comment: I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: Okay I will try to brief you. You requested to save a layout in the form of image at 2048 resolution. **Step 1:** convert layout to bitmap **step 2:** resize the bitmap to the desired size. **Step 3:** save the resized image to the gallery. The methods of implementing this can be done in many ways. I hope you this was helpful. If you need further more assistance. I suggest you to modify the question by adding some code.

Comment: I have completed the step 1. But i dont understand how do i resize the bitmap to my desired size. And while i am saving the bitmap (without resizing) the quality of the bitmap is degrade too much. I have added the screenshot of before and after saving the image into the device. Please have a look at it.